# How to split text to sentences when my text has many dots in-between sentences?

Tags: python, text, split, nlp

Requirements are:

1. Starting of the sentences must be a word with its first letter in capitals `( As, The, In)` ONLY and the end of the sentence should be a dot.
   eg:

   Input: `"This is a new book. I like to read this book"`

   Expected Output: `['This is a new book.' , 'I like to read this book']`
2. However, if there is citation present at the end of the sentence, it should be included in the sentence. In this case, the dot might be after the citation (or) before and after the citation.

eg:

Input: `"This is a new book.(Steve and Rasol 2014). I like to read this book (Rashi & Shabana 2015)."`

Expected Output: `['This is a new book.(Steve and Rasol 2014)' , 'I like to read this book (Rashi & Shabana 2015).']`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: r'\w. +\(\w. +\d{4} \) ' - This pattern worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
 [A-Z](.|\n)*?(\(.+?\))?\.(.|\n|$)(?!\()
```

**EDIT**

You can use this optimized regex

```
[A-Z](.|\n)*?\.(.|\n|$)(?!\()
```

- `[A-Z]` the sentences start with capital letter
- `(.|\n)*?` the sentences can have every character or new line
- `\.` the senteces end with the point...
- `(?!\()` ... and have no parentesis "(" after

Use this site for testing: https://regexr.com/

***Java Example***

```java
String s = "This is a new book. (Steve and Rasol 2014). I like to read this book (Rashi & Shabana 2015).";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Z](.|\\n)*?\\.(.|\\n|$)(?!\\()");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()) {
   for (int i = 0; i < matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
       System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the data you listed is seperated by `.`  you can split the data into an array with `array = data.split('. ')` command. Moreover for adding `.` at the end of each item you can iterate over the array and check if `.` exist at the end if not then append it.

Answer (score 0):

```
sentence = "This is a new book(Steve and Rasol 2014). " \
           "I like to read this book (Rashi & Shabana 2015)."
str = sentence.split(".")
print(str)
```

Output:

```
['This is a new book(Steve and Rasol 2014)', 'I like to read this book (Rashi & Shabana 2015).']
```

Comment: Your code will not do what the OP asks in the question. i.e. `'This is a new book.(Steve and Rasol 2014)'` would be incorrectly split into two strings.